# How can I find the versions of Python compatible with a specific version of a package?

Tags: python, pip

Say, for example, the package I'm interested in is `torch`. Using the `pip index versions` subcommand with the `--python-version` option, I can see which versions of `torch` are available for a given version of Python. I want to go the other way round: I want to know which versions of Python are compatible with a given version of `torch`. Is there a straightforward way to do this, using pip or another tool?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I have not found any table beyond what is available here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/. It would not be a bad idea if we start a lookup table in pytorch GitHub page.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, but I'm looking for a general solution that will work for any package, not just PyTorch.

Comment: Must’ve overlooked. Let me know if you find something.